# Strong type not working in subscribe from store

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, typescript-typings, angular7

I am using `Sublimetext 3` working the `angular 7` in the app, I am expecting the `autofill` from my model. but still i type something wrong from the object node, error is not through at all. is i required to add any plugin or something wrong with my code?

product state interface :

```
import { Product } from "./../product";
import * as fromRoot from "./../../state/app.state";

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
    products:ProductState
}

export interface ProductState {
    showProductCode : boolean;
    currentProduct : Product;
    products:Product[]
}
```

here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { Product } from '../product';
import * as fromProduct from  './../state/product.reducer';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  pageTitle = 'Products';
  errorMessage: string;

  displayCode: boolean;

  products: Product[];

  // Used to highlight the selected product in the list
  selectedProduct: Product | null;
  sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private store:Store<fromProduct.State>, private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.store.pipe(select('products')).subscribe((products) => {
      if(products){
        this.displayCode = products.xxx; //there is no xxx exist at all, no error, require auto fill here.

      }
    })
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you log what you get back from the store. Is it maybe an array of products instead of a single product?

Comment: actually I getting ` showProductCode : boolean;` here.

Comment: So instead of an actual Product object you get a string `showProductCode: boolean` ? That is strange.   

Regarding that you are missing typing it might be that it is inferring it to be of `any` type. You could have `subscribe((products: Product) => {`, which should solve your typing issue

Comment: But already I am extending the class `export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
    products:ProductState
}` where `Boolean` exist

Comment: `subscribe((products: ProductState) => {` is then what you want to use as type. Then your IDE should see the properties of the object